# mysql table design for daily rotation of top rating

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, rating

I store top-views and 'likes' in a table called 'counts'.  Once a night I run this query

```
UPDATE `counts` SET rank=d7+d6+d5+d4+d3+d2+d1,d7=d6,d6=d5,d5=d4,d4=d3,d3=d2,d2=d1,d1=0
```

Each day of the week has a d1-d7 variable, and we move it 'down' one each night and re-calculate the sum.

As my site has grown, this query now takes ~20 minutes.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to organize this more efficiently, as it seems like it might be a common pattern.

Comment: How big is the table that an update on it takes 20 minutes?

Comment: can we see your table schema

Comment: what else is in the counts table, ie what is the grain of it, and how many records are you talking about

Comment: That UPDATE will do a table-scan. Without changing table-structure there is no change you can make to the query itself to speed it up. (Not sure if you can gain speed by tweaking transaction logging.) You could pull the ID and the d1-d7 fields out to another table, or you could normalize as suggested in an answer below (though you would need to test to see if the latter makes things better or worse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, we need to see the schema. But I'll make a suggestion anyway. Don't have 7 different fields d1-d7. What if later you decide to keep the score over a year? Ouch.

I'm going to assume that `counts` has `view_id` as its PK. Then have another table `ranks` with columns `view_id` (set as FK into `counts`), `rank` (generalizes d1-d7, whatever datatype they are) and `rank_date`, which is a date. Now every night you have

```
UPDATE counts SET rank = (SELECT SUM(rank) FROM ranks r WHERE r.view_id=counts.view_id
                        AND r.rank_date>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) );
```

[Some RDBMSs allow a JOIN-type syntax in UPDATE queries. I believe MySQL understands something *similar to* the following, but it isn't my usual RDBMS

```
UPDATE counts, (SELECT view_id, SUM(rank) AS srank FROM ranks r 
                WHERE  r.rank_date>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
                GROUP BY r.view_id) AS q1 
SET rank = srank
WHERE counts.view_id=q1.view_id;
```

]

If so, that will probably run faster than the first version.

Meanwhile, optionally to clean up, you can delete rows from `ranks` that are more than 1 week old, but in a more flexible schema, you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks.  My table currently has about 5.5 million rows in it.  It currently also stores the total "view count", but I could move that into another table, then keep only items with rankings in the last week in it - much less. My experience joined updates like scares me off, but it's possible the ~100k rankings per week wouldn't really be that slow.  Thanks for the fresh perspective!